# Can't download workshop game from steam

Tags: steam, steam-workshop

I was trying to download a game from Steam. 
Terraforming Mars 
by
Tabletop Simulator>  Workshop > bringitonwimps's Workshop
But every-time I get this:

> This item has been added to your Subscriptions. Some games will require you to relaunch them before the item will be downloaded.

What do I do after this?

Comment: A subscription is from the Steam Workshop and it's usually a mod or extra content of some kind. You still need the base game. What workshop item are you trying to download? Is the base game installed?

Comment: Did you relaunch the game...?

Comment: Have you checked where workshop content would appear in your game?

Comment: @MageXy : The base workshop is Tabletop Simulator. I have not installed it as it is not available for free.
I am trying to download:
Terraforming Mars
from:
Tabletop Simulator>  Workshop > bringitonwimps's Workshop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot download anything from the Steam Workshop if you don't have the base game installed. You mentioned in the comments that you don't own Tabletop Simulator - if that's true, you will be unable to download the extra content because there's no *base* content to modify.

Purchase the base game, then launch it and all your Steam Workshop subscriptions should download automatically.